# JMockit MockUp for method with private class parameter

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I'm writing some unit tests using JUnit and JMockit and need to write a JMockit `MockUp` for a method that takes an instance of a private enum as an argument. Here's the the class I need to mock:

```
public class Result {
    //Static constants representing metrics
    public static final Metric AVOIDABLE = Metric.avoidable;
    public static final Metric UNAVOIDABLE = Metric.unavoidable;

    // private enumeration of metric values
    private enum Metric {avoidable, unavoidable};

    public Long getTodayCount(Metric metric) { //<- instance of private enum
        return getValueForKey(metric);
    }
}
```

depending on the specific `Metric` given I need to return a different `Long` value. If the `Metric` enum were public that would be straightforward enough. Something like:

```
private static class MockResult extends MockUp<Result> {
    @Mock
    Long getTodayCount(Metric m){ //<-- nope. Metric is private
        if(Result.AVOIDABLE.equals(m)){ //<-- can't call equals either
            return 1234L;    
        } else {
            return 4567L;
        }
    }
}
```

But since `Metric` is private is there any way to accomplish this aside from changing `Metric` to be public? That may end up being the only way to accomplish this, but I'm not the author of the `Result` class and am not completely familiar with the reasoning behind making `Metric` private in the first place.

Comment: Why not mock our Result class ?

Comment: It looks weird that the enum is private, but the constants are pubic. That does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation:

> The @Mock annotation marks those methods in the mock-up class which are meant to provide mock implementations for the corresponding methods **(of the same signature)** in the mocked class.

If the enum is private, you cannot use it in your unit tests as it will not be visible outside the class. Then you cannot define a proper MockUp.

**You have to either make `Metric` class more visible (at least package private) or mock out the whole `Result` class.**